# Limit inferior and limit superior proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Show that if $f$ is bounded on $[a,x_0)$, then $\varliminf_{x\rightarrow x_0^-} f(x) \le \varlimsup_{x\rightarrow x_0^-} f(x)$. I have absolutely no idea how to go about this. I can't understand the different between the limit inferior and limit superior.

Answer (score 1):

A good example I like to think of is the graph of $y=\sin(1/x)$ which looks something like [image: Y = sin(1/x)]

The liminf is the highest lower bound of the function as it approaches the point in question, whereas the limsup is the lowest upper bound for the function.  In this case, the liminf is -1 and the limsup is 1.  The fact that the two disagree means that the actual limit doesn't exist at zero.

Compare this to
[image: Y = x sin(1/x)]

For this, the liminf and limsup are both zero, so the limit itself is zero.

(images taken from google imagesearch, commons.wikimedia.org and [http://www.uec.tottori-u.ac.jp/~thashi/dat/cal/graph_x_sin_1_over_x.html](http://www.uec.tottori-u.ac.jp/%7Ethashi/dat/cal/graph_x_sin_1_over_x.html)  both of which labeled for reuse)

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: Although this answer doesn't address the question that the OP asked, I agree that it's more important for the OP to understand lim infs and lim sups - only than can he/she approach the problem asked.